# Running an existing project with CUDA and C++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, cuda

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/MarianoJT88/PD-Flow) project in my laptop. I've the following things installed.

**CUDA:**

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

**GCC:**

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) 5.4.1 20160904
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

**CMake:**

```
cmake version 3.5.1
```

During `make`. The project gives the following error.

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

If I add the `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` to `CMakesLists.txt` in order to support c++ standard 11. I get the following error.

```
In file included from /usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils.h:25:0,
                 from /home/muazzam/mywork/python/thesis/PD-Flow/scene_flow_visualization.h:24,
                 from /home/muazzam/mywork/python/thesis/PD-Flow/main_scene_flow_visualization.cpp:24:
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:253:8: error: ‘std::enable_if_t’ has not been declared
   std::enable_if_t<is_shared_ptr<T>::value>* = nullptr)
        ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:253:19: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
   std::enable_if_t<is_shared_ptr<T>::value>* = nullptr)
                   ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:263:8: error: ‘std::enable_if_t’ has not been declared
   std::enable_if_t<!is_shared_ptr<T>::value>* = nullptr)
        ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:263:19: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
   std::enable_if_t<!is_shared_ptr<T>::value>* = nullptr)
                   ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:261:6: error: ‘template<class RET, class T, class ... R> RET mrpt::utils::CStream::ReadVariant_helper(mrpt::utils::CSerializable::Ptr&, int)’ cannot be overloaded
  RET ReadVariant_helper(
      ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:251:6: error: with ‘template<class RET, class T, class ... R> RET mrpt::utils::CStream::ReadVariant_helper(mrpt::utils::CSerializable::Ptr&, int)’
  RET ReadVariant_helper(
      ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h: In member function ‘void mrpt::utils::CStream::WriteVariant(T)’:
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:314:15: error: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
   t.match([&](auto& o) { this->WriteObject(o); });
               ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h: In lambda function:
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:314:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘mrpt::utils::CStream::WriteObject(int&)’
   t.match([&](auto& o) { this->WriteObject(o); });
                                             ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:197:7: note: candidate: void mrpt::utils::CStream::WriteObject(const mrpt::utils::CSerializable*) <near match>
  void WriteObject(const CSerializable* o);
       ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:197:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:198:7: note: candidate: void mrpt::utils::CStream::WriteObject(const mrpt::utils::CSerializable&)
  void WriteObject(const CSerializable& o) { WriteObject(&o); }
       ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:198:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const mrpt::utils::CSerializable&’
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:524:28: error: ‘std::enable_if_t’ has not been declared
 template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<
                            ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:524:39: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
 template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<
                                       ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h: In function ‘mrpt::utils::CStream& mrpt::utils::operator<<(mrpt::utils::CStream&, const mapbox::util::variant<Types ...>&)’:
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CStream.h:545:17: error: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14
  pObj.match([&](auto& t) { out << t; });
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/TCamera.h:15:0,
                 from /usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CImage.h:16,
                 from /usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils.h:38,
                 from /home/muazzam/mywork/python/thesis/PD-Flow/scene_flow_visualization.h:24,
                 from /home/muazzam/mywork/python/thesis/PD-Flow/main_scene_flow_visualization.cpp:24:
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CConfigFileBase.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CConfigFileBase.h:80:22: error: ‘enable_if_t’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
      typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<enum_t>::value>>
                      ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CConfigFileBase.h:80:33: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
      typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_enum<enum_t>::value>>
                                 ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CConfigFileBase.h:96:22: error: ‘enable_if_t’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
      typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_enum<data_t>::value>>
                      ^
/usr/include/mrpt/base/include/mrpt/utils/CConfigFileBase.h:96:33: error: expected ‘>’ before ‘<’ token
      typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_enum<data_t>::value>>
                                 ^
In file included from /home/muazzam/mywork/python/thesis/PD-Flow/main_scene_flow_visualization.cpp:24:0:
/home/muazzam/mywork/python/thesis/PD-Flow/scene_flow_visualization.h:93:13: error: ‘COpenGLScenePtr’ in namespace ‘mrpt::opengl’ does not name a type
     opengl::COpenGLScenePtr  scene;
             ^
CMakeFiles/Scene-Flow-Visualization.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Scene-Flow-Visualization.dir/main_scene_flow_visualization.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Scene-Flow-Visualization.dir/main_scene_flow_visualization.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Scene-Flow-Visualization.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Scene-Flow-Visualization.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Now I've no idea how to make this work. How can I build this project?

Comment: Did you try to add the `-std=c++11` to your CMake flags?

Comment: hi Chiel, I am rather new to Cmake. Can you please tell me where should I add this line in the cmake file ?

Comment: I tried `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -std=c++11)` but gives me the same `std::enable_if_t` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::enable_if_t` was only introduced in C++14, so you should set the required standard to C++14:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

Comment: Hi thanks. That fixed most of the issues. But I am still getting this error. Is it somehow related ? `error: COpenGLScenePtr in namespace mrpt::opengl does not name a type opengl::COpenGLScenePtr  scene`

Comment: @Mj1992 Doesn't seem related.